# trying to switch images and change the value of the button alongside

Tags: javascript, html

I want to switch between smile and frown, simoultaneously changing the value of the button so that when the picture is frown he button says "Smile",and vice versa. But it does not seem to be working

```
    <html>
    <body>
        
        <img id="myImage" src="smile.png">
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Frown">
    </body>
    
<script>
    pic = document.getElementById('myImage')
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
    btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        if (btn.value="Frown") {
                pic.src="frown.png"
                btn.value="Smile"
            } else {
                pic.src="smile.png"
                btn.value="Frown"
            }
               
    })
        
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Single equal signs sets the value of the variable, double compares the two. It's a typo change your if statement to include two equal signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from your code, "Frown" will turn into "Smile", but it won't turn back into "Frown".

This is because every time you reach the part where it tests if btn.value is equal to "Frown" you have only one "=" sign. You're supposed to have two "==" like this:

```
   if (btn.value=="Frown")
```

If there isn't two "=" signs the program will just make btn.value be equal to "Frown" instead of checking if it is equal to it or not,

Answer (score 1):

check your if condition.  You need to use ==

```html
<html>
    <body>
        
        <img id="myImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/25">
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Frown">
    </body>
    
<script>
    pic = document.getElementById('myImage')
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
    btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{    
        if (btn.value == "Frown") {        
                pic.src="http://via.placeholder.com/50"
                btn.value="Smile"
            } else {                
                pic.src="http://via.placeholder.com/25"
                btn.value="Frown"
            }
               
    })
        
</script>

</html>
```